# After writing MACRO code - The formula give compile time syntax error. Without Macro works fine

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula

```
- 
=IF(K2="Missed KPI",IF(J2<>"null","Entry done after approx. "&ROUNDDOWN(NETWORKDAYS(F2,J2)-1-MOD(F2,1)+MOD(J2,1),0)&" work days"),IF(K2="Milestone Pending-Missed",IF(F2<>"null","Entry
-after"&ROUNDDOWN(NETWORKDAYS(F2,NOW())-1-MOD(F2,1)+MOD(NOW(),1),0)&" work days ago"," "),IF(K2="NA","Entry yet to be done-Order Not Raised- "&H2," ")))
```

Here:
K2 , J2, F2, H2 are cell names

When I use this formula without writing a Macro it works correctly. I have many other similar formulas all work correctly without MACRO. 
When I record a MACRO (not coding in VBA), when I try to run the MACRO it throws me a compile time - Syntax Error.

The below line is the VBA code (created during recording MACRO), for the above formula.

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-2]=""Missed KPI"",IF(RC[-3]<>""null"",""Entry done after approx. ""&ROUNDDOWN(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-7],RC[-3])-1-MOD(RC[-7],1)+MOD(RC[-3],1),0)&"" work days""),IF(RC[-2]=""Milestone Pending-KPI Missed"",IF(RC[-7]<>""null"",""Entry - after ""&ROUNDDOWN(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-7],NOW())-1-MOD(RC[-7],1)+MOD(NOW(),1),0)&"" work days ago"","" ""),IF("& _
    ""NA"",""CCD yet to be done-Order Not Raised- ""&RC[-5],"" "")))

"
```

As you can see that VBA has added some extra double quotes and also some text from the code is also missing after recording the MACRO.

Please help me with the solution as I am stuck here and don't know why my formula is not working.

For a small single line formula it is working fine but as soon as the formula move to another line in VBA (after recording MACRO) there is something wrong.

For this Formula -

```
=IF(K2="Approaching Deadline",(24-(NETWORKDAYS(F2,NOW())-1-MOD(F2,1)+MOD(NOW(),1))*24)/24," ")
```

It's recorded VBA version (which is in single line in VBA code)

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=IF(RC[-1]=""Approaching Deadline"",(24-(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-6],NOW())-1-MOD(RC[-6],1)+MOD(NOW(),1))*24)/24,"" "")"
```

It is working fine.

I have tried to work with quotations and multiple line break. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the recorded code is missing a cell reference. There are also some missing quotation marks and spaces (e.g. the `&` operator needs to have a space before and after it to work). Try this corrected code:

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(RC[-2]=""Missed KPI"",IF(RC[-3]<>""null"",""Entry done after approx. ""&ROUNDDOWN(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-7],RC[-3])-1-MOD(RC[-7],1)+MOD(RC[-3],1),0)&"" work days""),IF(RC[-2]=""Milestone Pending-KPI Missed"",IF(RC[-7]<>""null"",""Entry - after ""&ROUNDDOWN(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-7],NOW())-1-MOD(RC[-7],1)+MOD(NOW(),1),0)&"" work days ago"","" ""),IF(" & _
"RC[-2]=""NA"",""CCD yet to be done-Order Not Raised- ""&RC[-5],"" "")))"
```

Please note that this formula will lead to unwanted results if your `Selection` is between column `A` and `G`. It can only be used properly from column `H` onwards.